# How to plot a function in Python when both variables cannot be isolated to one side

Tags: function, matplotlib, variables, undefined, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to graph variable "u" versus variable "T" for 1<T<1000 (integers). However, the function I have includes both of the variables within an integral so I cannot create an isolated u=f(T) function. My thought process is to manipulate the function so that it is 0=f(T,u) and output a "u" value that minimizes f(T,u) for each T. However, I seem to be struggling a lot with how these variables and functions should be defined. All constants are defined and "E" should be defined through the integration step. The overall function I start with is:

5x10^28=integrate((pi/2)*(8*m/h^2)*(E^0.5)*(exp((E-u)/k*T)+1)^-1) from 0 to infinity and with respect to "E"

I am very new to python but the following code is how far I've been able to develop it based on previous forums and video tutorials. Any help is much appreciated!

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as spo

m=9.11e-31
h=6.63e-34
k=1.38e-23
T=list(range(1,1001))

def f(E,u):
    return (np.pi/2)*(8*m/(h**2))*(E**0.5)*(1/((np.exp((E-u)/k*T)+1)))


Func_Equal_Zero=quad(f,0,np.inf,args=(u,))[0]-5e-28


Start_Guess_T_u=[500,1e-5]

result=spo.minimize(Func_Equal_Zero,Start_Guess_T_u)
plt.plot(T,u)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.xlabel('Temperature (k)')
plt.ylabel('Chemical Potential (J)')
```

I expected that I could just define the functions including "u" but python does not seem to like what I have tried. I am not sure if any of my other syntax is not correct because I cannot get past its issue with defining "u".

Comment: Just a note on matplotlib. Calling plt.plot() and, afterwards, plt.figure() is unexpected. Are you sure? You may want to make the plt.figure() call first.

Comment: You want to plot an implicit equation, so maybe sympy's [implicit_plot](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) can help. However, this assumes that your equation is a sympy expression.